# t-sql update statement similar to cursor

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to use an update statement to iterate through rows of a table and assign a value to a single column of each row, depending on how previous and current values compare, which is similar to how a cursor would work.

initial table data:

```
|PK|EffectiveDate|ChangeDate|ActionType|
| 1|   2015-01-01|      NULL|       Add|
| 2|   2015-03-01|2015-03-01|    Change|
...
```

So, here's my code:

```
declare @prevPK int = null
        , @prevEffDate date = null
        , @prevChangeDate date = null
        , @prevActionType varchar(50) = null

update mytable
set ActionType = case when isnull(@prevChangeDate,'1900-01-01')<=ChangeDate then 'Change'
else 'Add'
end
, @prevPK = PK
, @prevEffDate = prevEffDate
, @prevChangeDate = prevChangeDate
, @prevActionType = prevActionType
```

... and this will update the variables for each row and do the comparison and set the ActionType for each row appropriately; however, the case statement is not evaluating appropriately.

Do I have the set assignment in the right order?

This is on SQL Server 2008 R2.

Please let me know if you need any further clarification.
Thanks!
-Wesley

Comment: In SQL Server 2008 if you have a large number of rows in a table it may be more efficient to use a cursor, rather than self-joining the table. In SQL Server 2012+ you can use `LAG` function to get the value from a "previous" row.

Comment: If really row by row operation necessary for your requirement,then recursive CTE is not bad.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov,how cursor can be efficient when i can do same thing using self join ?

Comment: @KumarHarsh, self join has `O(n*n)` complexity, cursor is `O(n)`.

Comment: If I understand O(n*n) correctly then,guess we can avoid O(n*n) complexity in self join or Recursive CTE.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (isnt fully tested, but should give you the idea of where to go):

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (pk int, changedate datetime, ActionType varchar(50))

INSERT INTO #Test
SELECT 1, NULL, NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '2015-01-01', NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '2015-02-01', NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, '2015-03-01', NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, '2015-04-01', NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, NULL, NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, '2015-01-01', NULL


;WITH tableData AS (
    SELECT pk, ChangeDate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY pk) AS RowNum
    FROM #Test
)
UPDATE #Test SET
    ActionType = x.ActionType
FROM (
    SELECT T.pk, CASE WHEN isnull(TPrev.ChangeDate,'1900-01-01') <= T.ChangeDate THEN 'Change' ELSE 'Add' END AS ActionType
    FROM tableData T
    LEFT JOIN tableData TPrev ON TPrev.RowNum - 1 = T.RowNum
) X WHERE X.pk = #Test.pk

SELECT *
FROM #Test
```

It basically uses ROW_NUMBER to ensure sequential ids (in case one is skipped or filtered)

Then self joins on itself to get previous record.

Then does an update-from to update the field.